# What is the equivalent of Rails.application.assets in a production environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

I'm using Sass::Engine to compile a css file dynamically, and I need to pass the environment and load paths to sprockets.  This works just fine in development:

```
def compile_scss
  view_context = ActionView::Base.new
  environment = Rails.application.assets

  # body and filename are instance variables created elsewhere        
  @compiled_file = Sass::Engine.new(body,
                                    filename: filename,
                                    syntax: :scss,
                                    cache: false,
                                    load_paths: environment.paths,
                                    sprockets: {
                                      context: view_context,
                                      environment: environment
                                    }).render
end
```

but fails in production because `Rails.application.assets` is `nil`.  What is the equivalent in production?

Comment: assets are served from the public folder in production when compiled.

Comment: @bkunzi01 Thanks for responding.  So maybe I'm thinking about it wrong?  There is no need for Rails.application.assets in production since the assets are precompiled, and served by ngix.  So maybe I need to back up a bit and see how assets:precompile (maybe?) initializes the environment and try to replicate that.

Comment: Yes.  Normally when precompiling assets you'd run "bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production") and thus are specifying which environment config file it will utilize for the compiling.  After running it, you'll notice it will have populated your public folder with fingerprinted assets.

Comment: Just leaving this here because it would have helped me to adjust the asset cache for Rails 5: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#assets-cache-store

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rails.application.assets is always `nil` in production because the assets are precompiled and served from the public folder (thanks to @bkunzi01 for that).  Also, Sprockets only needs the asset paths to be passed to it in order to run, not the environment.  The paths are available from `Rails.application.config.assets.paths`.  I was able to get my stylesheet compiler working with the following method.

```
def compile_scss
  view_context = ActionView::Base.new
  environment = Rails.application.assets || Rails.application.config.assets

  # body and filename are instance variables created elsewhere        
  @compiled_file = Sass::Engine.new(body,
                                    filename: filename,
                                    syntax: :scss,
                                    cache: false,
                                    load_paths: environment.paths,
                                    sprockets: {
                                      context: view_context,
                                    }).render
end
```